# How can I deploy web package from Powershell using WebDeploy 3 cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, web-deployment, msdeploy, webdeploy

I want to use new WebDeploy 3 cmdlets like Sync-WD*.

How can I sync from "package" to "auto" using SetParameters.xml and credentials?

p.s. And where's some real documentation, MS?!

Comment: any final solution about it with full source code sample ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, I totally forgot about this question. I've added my answer but it's a sad one.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. I've found no answers unfortunately.
I've used this approach instead:
https://github.com/SathishN/PSBuildModules/blob/master/Src/MSDeploy.psm1